# Google Chrome on Android - How to programmatically enable some items in chrome://flags by modifying source code and rebuilding a new chrome.apk?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have the source code of Chrome and I will build a new .apk of chrome. Then, how can I modify some codes or files related to building or other files to realize that the item named "webVR" in chrome://flags is enabled when the app first runs.

Comment: Can't you just `request a token for your site's origin (domain)` as per: https://webvr.rocks/chrome_for_android if you are trying to get webVR to run on a Android device?

Comment: I means that I'm modifying the chrome's install package. I'm working for a phone producing company. We want to change the source code to produce a config file that can enable the "webVR" in chrome://flags. And changing the config file can changing the default value of the "webVR".

Comment: There is a button showing "reset all to default" at the top right corner of the page chrome://flags. I want to know that, how to modify the "default" value here. In another words, no matter what value of the item "webVR" now, once user click the button "Reset all to default", the value of item "webVR" become "enabled".